# Prepopulate lookup field in e.force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, create-records

I am trying to complete Lightning Framework specialist superbadge in trailhead and under challenge 2, I came across the following

If a Boat Type is selected, the new Boat record defaults to the selected Boat Type

I am using "e.force:createRecord"

to create a new boat record. However boattype field is a lookup and Salesforce documentation says you cannot pre-populate the Id fields.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm

Controller JS Code

```
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Boat__c",
        "defaultFieldValues": {
            'Phone' : '415-240-6590',
            'Account' : '001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
```

Is there any workaround for the above?

Comment: Are you referring to `You can’t prepopulate system-maintained fields, such as Id or record modification time stamps. Default values for these fields are silently ignored.` in the documentation? That means you cant change the Id of a record. But there is no restriction of populating lookup field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boat Type is a Lookup Field to Boat_Type Object and We can prepopulate the Lookup and Master-Detail Fields. As in the Link that you shared it's defining that **You can’t prepopulate system-maintained fields, such as Id or record modification time stamps. Default values for these fields are silently ignored.**

> It means we can not prepopulate the RecordId, createdDate,
>   LastModifieddate

I am using the below Code for the same.

```
var boatTypeCmp = component.find('boatTypes');
        var boatType = boatTypeCmp.get('v.value');
        if(boatType !="" && boatType !=null && boatType != undefined){
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Boat__c",
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    'BoatType__c' : boatType
                }
            });
        }else{
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Boat__c"
            });
        }
```

Where **boatTypes** is the Aura:id of the picklist field.

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused, the link made me think you couldn't populate lookup fields by using ID's.  I am doing something similar to the above trying to create a case from a contact record via a lightning component.  One of the first fields I tried to prepopulate was the "Contact" field.  I am passing the recordId successfully (javascript alert shows me this) yet the field mapping within the createRecordEvent.setParams of "'contact': recordId' is simply ignored (no error and other fields are mapped correctly?